# what is the best way to retrieve a node in adobe cq5?

Tags: aem, sling

What are the different ways to retrieve a node in adobe cq5 and out of those which has to prefer.

I knows three method only one is through session , request and another one is through resourceResolver.
Here are those..

```
Node rootNode = session.getNode(path);  
by request
Node currentNode = request.getResource().adaptTo(Node.class);

by resourceResolver

    String resourcePath = "path/to/resource";
    Node.node = resourceResolver.getResource(resourcePath).adaptTo(Node.class);
```

Out of these which one one is best way to retrieve and why ?

Comment: what is the use case ?

Answer (score 4):

First it is discouraged to ask question like this, as it triggers oppinion based answers. Nonetheless I try to be as objecitve as I can. I think it depends on the use case, e.g. where in your code do you want to get the node:

- If you already are in a servlet,
  `request.getResource().adaptTo(Node.class)` is probably the most
  straightforward way.
- If you already have a jcr `Session`, it is easiest to use the
  `getNode(path)` method
- If you already have a `ResourceResolver` `getResource(path)` or `resolve(path)` are fine as well.

Me personally prefer the Sling API over the JCR, so I usually work with Resources anyway thus I mostly use the `ResourceResolver` or its Adapters: `PageManager`, `TagManager`, etc.

I even think internally it all ends up with `session.getNode(path)` as the `ResourceResolver` relies on a `Session` (you can adapt it to it) and `request.getResource()` probably uses the `resolve(path)` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best way".  If you already have a NODE object then if you are trying to get say... all the children then there is listChildren().  Really the best way is a use case.

The real question is why you want a NODE specifically.  Unless you are creating data in the JCR, there is usually no need for the node interface.  99% of the time the system handles node creation for you, so you are reading data, in which case resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class) is probably your best bet.

If you add more details about WHY you are concerned about this and the context, I can help you further.